# I can not wrap my mind how to show images using img tags. I am getting a file through<input type="file"/>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, input, react-hooks

I am getting this data from an input when I check it in my console.

File {name: "photo_2021-08-25_23-04-02.jpg", lastModified: 1629921880548, lastModifiedDate: Wed Aug 25 2021 23:04:40 GMT+0300 (Moscow Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 61087, …}

`<form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}> {console.log(postProduct.selectedFile[0])} <input name="selectedFile" type="file" multiple={true} accept=".jpeg, .png, .jpg" onChange={(e) => {setPostProduct({ ...postProduct,selectedFile: e.target.files,});}}/>`

and in my image tag where the image should be shown

```
  <img className={classes.img} src={product.selectedFile[0]} alt={product.title}/> {console.log(product.selectedFile[0])}
```

I am getting this type of data **data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtc....**
which weighs 1.7Mb. It is not rendering on the page. When I try to access object property as it shown above it is not working and on image tag it gives an error of [0] undefined, though there are properties with keys like 0 , 1 and etc.

Comment: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/...` that is the image, a base64 version of its contents, just put it as a string on the `src` attribute of the img tag , `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/...." />`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Base64 images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Comment: "I am getting this type of data" — Are you? Because it looks like you are passing the file directly to the `src` prop without using FileReader to convert it to a `data` URL.

Answer (score -1):

I could not understand your question completely. But the way I show an image by control input file from Client is using an API:

Firstly: upload the image, send to the server, the server save the image and response the image's URL.

Secondly: you set the server response URL for the image's source.